# How many gallons are used in the U.S. each day and if this gasoline were used to fill a cubical tank how big would one side be?

Tags: geometry, mathematical-physics, unit-of-measure

The question I am trying to solve is:

Part I) How many gallons of gasoline are used in the U.S. in one day assuming there are $2$ cars for every $3$ people and each car is driven $10,000$ miles a year and averages $20$ miles per gallon.

Part II) If this gasoline were used to fill a cubical tank, how big would one side of the tank be?

I think my part I is correct.

I got $273972602.7$ gallons of gasoline used in US each year

My work: $$300 \text{million people} \times \frac{2 \text{cars}}{3 \text{people}}\times \frac{27.397 \text{mi/day}}{1 \text{car}}\times \frac{1 \text{gallon}}{ 20 \text{miles}}$$

However, I am not sure how to approach and solve part II.

I am not sure what information I can extract from the problem to solve this.

Thank you. Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Convet your volume into litters. Then take the qube root of the amount of gasoline in litters. This will give you the side of the cube in $10$'s of centimeters. Divide by $10$ and you will get it in meters.

In other words, denote the length of the side by $l$, the amount of gasoline by $g$. Then $$l=\sqrt[3]{g}$$

Comment: What should I assume for density?

Comment: @XiJiaopin, I made an edit. I made a mistake. You don't need the density, since you already have the volume. The cube root of volume is length.